# Passing array from one servlet to other

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I need to pass an array of strings from one servlet to another so i put it in session.

Code for servlet 1 :

```
String[] finalshares=new String[shares.size()]; where shares is being a arraylist already defined earler in my servlet
String arrayID = "finalshares";
request.getSession().setAttribute(arrayID, finalshares);
```

Now int other servlet i do :

```
String[] finalshares=(String[]) request.getSession().getAttribute("arrayID");
```

But it gives NullPointerException.Please help

Comment: instead of `arrayID` in `getAttribute` use `finalshares`

Answer (score 1):

You have to get it with:

```
String[] finalshares=(String[]) request.getSession().getAttribute("fileshares");
```

This (`"fileshares"`) is the id you've set for the session attribute.

Comment: here arrayId is the id I had set for fileshares

Comment: `arrayId` is the variable name, not the variable value.